# Heroku: Error - /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, npm, yarnpkg

I have a **Rails 6** Application which I just built.

However, when I try deploying to Heroku from my command line using:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the error below after some :

```
yarn install v1.22.4

   [1/4] Resolving packages...

   [2/4] Fetching packages...

   info fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.

   info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

   [3/4] Linking dependencies...
   [4/4] Building fresh packages...
   success Saved lockfile.
   $ npm run build
   /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
   error Command failed with exit code 127.
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I have re-run the command several times, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

The issue was because I did not have a Nodejs Build pack to run the `npm run build` command for assets compilation.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I added the Nodejs buildpack to the application with the `buildpacks:add` command:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

This will insert the Node.js buildpack at the first position in the order of buildpack execution, and move the other buildpacks that are ahead of it down one position.

**Note**: The buildpack for the primary language of your app should be the last buildpack added. In this case `Ruby` is our primary language.

You can then view the buildpacks for your application:

```
heroku buildpacks 

=== nameless-brushlands-4859 Buildpack 
1. heroku/nodejs 
2. heroku/ruby
```

**Note**: The last buildpack in the list will be used to determine the process types for the application.

You should always specify a **Node.js version**, **npm version** and **yarn version** that matches the runtime you’re developing and testing with. To find your version locally:

```
node --version
npm --version
yarn --version
```

Now, use the engines section of the `package.json` to specify the version of **Node.js**, **npm version** and **yarn version** to use on Heroku.

```
"version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x",
    "npm": "6.x",
    "yarn": "1.x"
  },
```

Now you can deploy to Heroku and it will work fine:

```
git add .
git commit -m "add nodejs buildpack"
git push heroku master
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**